Market Not Found Error using @project-serum/serum library on Devnet
I am write a script to execute a buy order on serum @project-serum/serum and @solana/web3.js libraries.
Getting " Error: Market not found" even though this address  https://solscan.io/account/AgFnRLUScRD2E4nWQxW73hdbSN7eKEUb2jHX7tx9YTYc?cluster=devnet
is present on devnet. What could be the reason?
